# Conic intersection between circle and ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles, conic-sections

So I need to find the intersection between these two:

> $4x^2+16y^2-64=0$ and $x^2+y^2=9$

Following a similar approach of substitution, I was able to get 4 points: $(\sqrt {20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (\sqrt{-20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (\sqrt{-20/3},\sqrt{-7/3}), (\sqrt{20/3}, \sqrt{-7/3})$. But the answer says $(3,0) and (-3,0)$... What went wrong?

Comment: Without your work, it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: The answer is incorrect because the points $(\pm 3,0)$ do not lie on the ellipse.

Comment: Hm... I solved it and got the right answer. Wolfram Alpha also says that's the right answer. It looks like the only thing you did wrong was not simplifying the radicals.

Comment: Moreover the points with coordinates $\sqrt{-20/3}$ are "imaginary" points.

Answer (score 3):

$4x^2+16y^2-64=0$ and $x^2+y^2=9$

One little picture says more than a long speech!

[image]

In your answer : 
$$(\sqrt {20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (\sqrt{-20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (\sqrt{-20/3},\sqrt{-7/3}), (\sqrt{20/3}, \sqrt{-7/3})$$ the signs $-$ are not at right places. The correct typing is :
$$(\sqrt {20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (-\sqrt{20/3}, \sqrt{7/3}), (-\sqrt{20/3},-\sqrt{7/3}), (\sqrt{20/3}, -\sqrt{7/3})$$
Obviously $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$ are not correct. Probably there is a typo in the wording of the problem and/or given solution.

If they are only two points of intersection $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$ one possibility is : $4x^2+16y^2=36$.

[image]

Another possibility with non-concentric circle and ellipse :  $4x^2+16(y+c)^2=64 \quad,\quad c=\pm\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$.

[image]

They are other possibilities with non-concentric circle and ellipse (bigger ellipses).